# why my add list always move to the top of list after second click?

Tags: android, arraylist

i want to make a list item with 2 button yes and no, when each button clicked, i want to show new list item, but when i already click yes and no, the next item is show on top of list. i want to make it always show at the end of list.
`My Adapter`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fTSM.jpg)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FaultHolder holder, final int position) {

    Integer Nomer = list.size();
    int number = position+1;
    holder.textOut.setText("Pertanyaan");
    holder.numberOut.setText(""+number);


    holder.addYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             TestFaultModel faultyes = new TestFaultModel("",position-1,number,true);
            holder.addYes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list.clear();
            list.add(faultyes);
            updateList(list);
        }
    });

    holder.addNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final TestFaultModel faultno = new TestFaultModel("",position-1,number,false);
            holder.addNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            list.clear();
            list.add(faultno);
            updateList(list);
        }
    });

    holder.send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String text = holder.textInput.getText().toString().trim();
            final Integer numberStep = Integer.valueOf(holder.numberOut.getText().toString().trim());

            holder.textInput.setEnabled(false);
            holder.send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            faultInterface.onClick(text,numberStep);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void updateList(ArrayList<TestFaultModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

anyone can help?

Comment: list.add(list.size - 1, item)

Comment: Still not work with this code:(

Comment: is that list adapter? or recycler adapter???

Comment: Recycler adapter